# Splitting large text field c#

Tags: c#, text, split

EDIT: i have problem which i cant solve. I have large text file. I want select from this file only special data for me.

My code:

```
class Program
{
    static string ticket = "";
    static string openTime = "";
    static string type = "";
    static float size;
    static string item = "";
    static float price;
    static string closeTime = "";
    static float priceC;
    static float commission;
    static float swap;
    static float trade;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadFile.ReadAllFile("..\\..\\..\\File.txt");
    }
}

public static class ReadFile
{
    public static string ReadAllFile(string file)
    {
        string content = "";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(content);
        return content;
    }
}
```

One line from text file:

> 18388699   2021.09.03 14:40:14    buy 0.01    eurusd  1.18720 1.16211 1.17961     1.17201 0.00    -0.69   -12.96

In this text there are spaces. I want split this values to my strings.
This code reads the whole text from this text file. But i need select only data to my string from this file. Is there some method or funkcion which can select only important text passages?

Sorry for previous post, i dont want whole script. I am sreaching for some tips and tricks how to do that :D English is not my native language, then i cant describe my problem perfectly, but i tried my best :D

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would make it easier for people to answer your question if you would post a representative part of the data your working with as text in the question, rather than adding a link to an image.

Comment: Could you provide the *text file* as a *text*, please?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO sorry but this kind of request is out of topic on SO, this is not a code on demand site but a Q&A. I suggest to try your self to write a  parser and come back here when you find yourself in trouble

Comment: Thanks you for the welcome. I tried describe my problem, but my english does not allow me to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"..\..\..\File.txt"))
    {
        var fields = line.Split();

        var ticket = fields[0];
        var openTime = DateTime.Parse(fields[1] + " " + fields[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var price = decimal.Parse(fields[6], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Console.WriteLine($"{ticket}, {openTime}, {price}");
    }
}
```

- Read each `line` of the file using [File.ReadLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-5.0#System_IO_File_ReadLines_System_String_).
- Split on spaces using [String.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_Char___).
- Index into the `fields` to get at the data you want.

  - `ticket` is just the first field.
  - For `openTime` you need to join the second and third field. I also chose to parse to a `DateTime`.
  - For things like prices and quantities I would use a `decimal` data type. In your code you have a `float`, I would not use that. `float`'s have very low precision, you might get round off error with those. `double`'s are better, but might still have the same problem. The recommended data type for calculations like these is `decimal`.

Comment: This is what i need. I know how to read and parse json or csv because there are char symbol between words. But in this case there are spaces. Thanks a lot for help